# WatchKit - TableView with special effect

Tags: watchkit

I would like to create a tableView on an Apple Watch app with a specific effect... You can see it in this [video](https://youtu.be/unNBpW64CLM?t=120) (go to 2 min). This is a different effect than the default one. I don't know how to do this, if anybody can help me by explaining me how I can do this, it would be nice :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use SpriteKit to get such a behaviour on Apple Watch but will have to setup a tableView manually by yourself.